# Filename Integer value getting Appended instead of Incrementing

Tags: python

I have a python code and I am making an API call in a loop.
The result of the API is a pdf file which I am saving at a location.
I want to save the pdfs as name1, name2, name3 and so on.
However in my code I am not sure what I am doing wrong the files are getting saved as name1, name12, name123 and so on.

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
# USE SEJDA API TO CONVERT HTML TO PDF
import requests
from pathlib import Path
# api_key = input('Enter your api-key: ')
api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
url = "https://api.sejda.com/v2/html-pdf"

Path("D:\").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
fileName = testPdf
counter = 0

while url_to_convert in all_urls:
    
    fileName = fileName + str(counter)
    counter = counter + 1
    r = requests.post(
        url,
        json={
            "url": url_to_convert,
            "viewportWidth": 1200,
            "hideNotices" : True,
            "usePrintMedia" : True,
        },
        headers={"Authorization": "Token: {}".format(api_key)},
    )
    open("D:\\" + fileName +".pdf", "wb").write(r.content)
    print(url_to_convert)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding two strings will result in what you are getting. So, basically you are adding the counter to same file name, which results in what you are getting.

```
fileName = fileName + str(counter)
```

Change this instead to:

```
file_name = fileName + str(counter)
```

Use this `file_name` in the `write` operation.

Comment: Thanks.. I knew I was doing something silly ...appreciate your help